# VB.NET Copy Dirs into new Dir same Path, Error "process access being used by another process."

Tags: vb.net

Here Is my code

```
Public Sub MoveAllFolders(ByVal fromPathInfo As DirectoryInfo, ByVal toPath As String)
    Dim toPathInfo = New DirectoryInfo(toPath)
    If (Not toPathInfo.Exists) Then
        toPathInfo.Create()
    End If
    'move all folders
    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In fromPathInfo.GetDirectories()
        dir.MoveTo(Path.Combine(toPath, dir.Name))
    Next
End Sub
```

MoveAllFolders("D:\Users\TheUser!\Desktop\dd", "D:\Users\TheUser!\Desktop\dd\Folders)

My goal is to move all folder inside a folder into a folder named Folders.
so If I do it on desktop all the folders in desktop will go to "Folders"

but I get an error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
so this code can't work this way, so is there any way to do what I wanna do?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Don't use `.Exists` like that.  Instead, just call create and handle the exception if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving your target-directoy into itself.

You could check if the destination-path  contains the source-directory's `FullName`.

```
If Not toPath.Contains(fromPathInfo.FullName) Then
    dir.MoveTo(IO.Path.Combine(toPath, dir.Name))
 End If
```

But this method would be quite hacky. Consider a folder '"D:\abc1' and a folder '"D:\abc2'. `Contains` would return `true` in this case even if the folder "abc1" and "abc2" are not the same.

This should work better:

```
Public Sub MoveAllFolders(ByVal fromDir As IO.DirectoryInfo, ByVal toDir As IO.DirectoryInfo, Optional ByVal excludeList As List(Of String) = Nothing)
    If (Not toDir.Exists) Then
        toDir.Create()
    End If
    'move all folders
    For Each dir As IO.DirectoryInfo In fromDir.GetDirectories()
        Dim targetPath = IO.Path.Combine(toDir.FullName, dir.Name)
        If Not toDir.FullName = dir.FullName _
            AndAlso Not IsParentDirectory(toDir, dir) _
            AndAlso Not IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath) _
            AndAlso (excludeList Is Nothing _
              OrElse Not excludeList.Contains(dir.FullName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
            Try
                dir.MoveTo(targetPath)
            Catch ioEx As IO.IOException
                'ignore this directory'
            Catch authEx As UnauthorizedAccessException
                'ignore this directory'
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Function IsParentDirectory(ByVal subDir As IO.DirectoryInfo, ByVal parentDir As IO.DirectoryInfo) As Boolean
    Dim isParent As Boolean = False
    While subDir.Parent IsNot Nothing
        If subDir.Parent.FullName = parentDir.FullName Then
            isParent = True
            Exit While
        Else
            subDir = subDir.Parent
        End If
    End While
    Return isParent
End Function
```

You could use this function in this way:

```
Dim excludePathList As New List(Of String)
excludePathList.Add("C:\Temp\DoNotMoveMe1\")
excludePathList.Add("C:\Temp\DoNotMoveMe2\")
MoveAllFolders(New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp\"), New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp\temp-sub\"), excludePathList)
```

*Edit: updated according to your last comment (untested).*

Comment: Tim, Thanks so much It's probbaly my fault for not mentioning that I use string for toDir "Dim todir4 = (fbd.SelectedPath + "/" + TextBox2.Text)" and I get this error "value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.DirectroyInfo'"

Comment: Never Mind fixed using "Dim todir4 = New DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath + "/" + TextBox2.Text)"

Comment: Tim! I wan't to be able to exclude few folders names or if folder is in use to skip any idea about that? Your code is too complicated for me what ever I try i can't do it. tried for 1hour+ >.<

Comment: @Mark: i've edited my answer according to your last comment. I haven't tested it but it should work(there is always a range for improvement, f.e. with handling trailing slashes).

Comment: Thanks it looks really good, Just small error at "StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase" "Error 9 Too many arguments to 'Public Function Contains(item As T) As Boolean'"

Comment: @Mark: you don't have .NET-Framework 4.0? This is the LinQ overloaded version of contains.

Comment: @Mark: if you are on 4.0, did you add a reference to `Sytem.Core`? The extension methods for linq live there.

Comment: @Mark: i'e also changed a little and added braces around the last condition: `AndAlso (excludeList Is Nothing _
              OrElse Not excludeList.Contains(dir.FullName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then`

Comment: Sorry fall a sleep yesterday, I use Framework 2.0 because many people do not have 4.0 don't want to trouble them and make them download it, do you think it can be done with 2.0? I don't have System.core on it ;/

Comment: @Mark: consider to use @Tim in front of your comment,because otherwise i'm not noticed about new comments, have a look at [this Meta-Link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for further informations. You can use the `contains` version without the StringComparer parameter without any problems. You only have to remember that this is **case-sensitive**. So you could f.e. use `excludeList.Contains(dir.FullName.ToLower())` and you should ensure that the excludelist also contains only lowered case paths.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter didn't knew about @Tim well I tried excludeList.Contains(dir.FullName.ToLower()) doesn't seems to work :< But without .tolower it works! and it's not case-sensitive! Thanks a lot Tim it looks like it works perfectly now